# in C Language what is Ftell() equivalent on delphi

Tags: c, delphi

i am working on C source to translate to delphi but i was stuck on reading files on ftell() function, can you help me find the equivalent function in delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object of type `File`, then you may use the `FilePos()` function, [described here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FilePos).

Comment: And if it is a stream then strm.position